# Merge/Join Multi-index Dataframes and combine columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframe that are multi-index, while preserving the highest level index. The problem is merging on axis=1 results in the below two columns. Merging/joining on axis=0 drops any value in the 0_y column that has the same sub-index as an entry in )_x. An example below is (226,0), where the value 1510123295301 gets dropped if I merge/join on axis=0.

Is there any way to merge two multi-index dataframes into a single column, preserving the primary index (e.g. 226), but expanding to include non-duplicates in the right-hand column (e.g. 226(0-6))?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `df2.combine_first(df)`?

Comment: I tried that, but it drops anything in the second dataframe with the same index as the first. For example, the (226,0) 1510123295301 is dropped.

Comment: Then would you do `df.combine_first(df2)`? You could just reverse the dataframes.

Comment: Then it drops 014113734066. If an entry in both columns has both a primary and secondary index in common, one of the entries will get dropped. I need the subindex to expand to merge entries from both columns.